# How to get the "in-sample" predicted values (y hat) in statsmodel ols?

Tags: python, regression, statsmodels

Here is the code:

```
from   statsmodels.formula.api import ols
import io
import requests

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RInterested/datasets/gh-pages/mtcars.csv"
contents = requests.get(url).content
mtcars = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(contents.decode('utf-8')))
print(mtcars.describe())
reg = ols('mpg ~ C(cyl) + wt', data=mtcars).fit() 
print(reg.summary())
```

This seems to return an intercept for the model, and the syntax is very similar to R, which I like. There is a `reg.predict` and a `reg.get_predict` within the `print(dir(reg))`, but neither one of them return the predicted values for each example (case or subject) in the dataset. It seems as though it may be waiting for an "out-of-sample" array to spit out these predicted values.

I would like to get the predicted `mpg` for the examples in the actual dataset plotted as points of a different color to the actual data cloud, and superimposed on the regression line:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The in-sample predictions are available as `reg.fittedvalues` attribute on the results instance, and when calling predict without arguments, `reg.predict()`.

When the predict method has additional options, then those can be computed for in-sample observations by not specifying a new set of explanatory variables, `exog`.

Comment: You are ideal to answer a quick follow-up question... I am trying to use Python more, and your package statsmodel seems as seamless as it gets, but I don't understand the OLS (no intercept) versus the ols (intercept)...

Comment: OLS and all models use numpy arrays or pandas dataframe as data. This is the main interface when users or packages that use statsmodels already have the data prepared. statsmodels takes them as they are and doesn't change them. The formula interface, e.g. lower case `ols`, which is an alias for `OLS.from_formula`, incorporates some of the data preparation steps like adding intercept and converting categorical variable to some numerical encoding, e.g. creating dummy variables.